# Problem with deploying frontend to heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, web-deployment, typeorm

I have a typeorm project with that structure:

[image]

In both client and root, index files are located in src directory.
In package.json in client directory I changed one thing("build") and added proxy:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && mv build ../public",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "gen": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml"
  },
"proxy": "http://localhost:4000"
```

In src/index.ts I made that:

```
const app = express();
...
app.get("/", (_req, res) => res.send("hello"));
app.use(express.static('../public'));

    app.get('*', (_, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'))
    });

  
    const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
  
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

And part of package.json from root directory:

```
...
"scripts": {
      "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
      "server": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
      "client": "npm start --prefix client",
      "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
   }
```

And it works when I run it on localhost, but when I deployed on heroku it shows me that, what I get on backend(on port 4000), that is this "hello".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's good. I just passed invalid path to espress.static:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```